# How to receive location updates after reboot

Tags: location, google-play-services, android-7.0-nougat, android-8.0-oreo

I am using this sample for receiving location updates :

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesPendingIntent

It receives location after I register a location request using a connected instance of Google API Client.
My question is how can I re-register Google Api Client after device reboots? Some say Android O will put restrictions on background services, so a service is not recommended?

I found this link useful, but still don't know about actual behavior of OS and whether treating my app as foreground or background?

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html#services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how can I re-register Google Api Client after device reboots?

Register a `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest for the `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast. Then, in its `onReceive()` method, re-register your request for location updates.

> Some say Android O will put restrictions on background services, so a service is not recommended?

Whether you use a service for registering for location updates or for processing a location update depends on what work is needed at either of those points. If you are doing any sort of I/O (disk I/O, network I/O, etc.), you should use a service.

What Android O changes is that:

- a pure background service can only run for about a minute; if you may need more time than that, you will need to consider using a foreground service
- location updates will be delivered less frequently to background apps

Comment: Interesting!, did you read about pure background service and ONE MINUTE time in Google Documents?

Comment: @AVEbrahimi: The one minute time is based on my own experiments with Android O; the documentation indicates that it will be "several minutes".

Comment: Google documents say in Android O system will report location updates once every 30 mins, but what if user moves frequently in this period, will it report in shorter times?

Comment: you said " re-register your request for location updates", but it takes time to connect to Google API Client, broadcast receiver will terminate and I can't receive OnConnected message, what shall I do?

Comment: This document https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html says "Another foreground app is connected to the app, either by binding to one of its services or by making use of one of its content providers", is Google Play Services considered another app and it keeps my app alive?

Comment: @AVEbrahimi: "it takes time to connect to Google API Client, broadcast receiver will terminate and I can't receive OnConnected message, what shall I do?" -- ah, sorry, I forgot about that part. You probably will need a `Service` briefly for setting things up, with the `BroadcastReceiver` passing control to the `Service`. "is Google Play Services considered another app and it keeps my app alive?" -- no, because *you* are binding to *Play Services*, not the other way around.